# "Optional" end of line $ literal (non greedy)

Tags: regex, non-greedy, end-of-line

I would like to make the "end of line" character ($) "optional" (or non-greedy).
Meaning, I want to capture a certain pattern at the end of the line, or none.
This is the regex I've built:

```
(.+\s*)\s*(?:(\(\s*[xX\*]\s*\d+\s*\))|$)
```

I would like to capture things like

```
Incompatible device (x10) ; Boot sequence aborted
```

What i'd want is, to be able to capture the first string here (**Incompatible device (x10)**), but if the quantifier **(x10)** does not appear, to be able to capture just the second one (**Boot sequence aborted**, without a `(x##)` after it).
if I test the pattern on

```
boot sequence aborted
```

It does get captured, however, if I test it on the whole string above, everything is captured, and I only need the "Incompatible device" part.

Comment: You mean this https://regex101.com/r/sY4uC9/2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close: all you need is replacing `.`, which matches any character, with `[^;]`, like this:

```
([^;]+\s*)\s*(?:(\(\s*[xX\*]\s*\d+\s*\))|$)
```

Now your expression would capture the first part if `(x10)` is present ([demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/qL5dE8/1)), or the second part if it is missing ([demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/eS1kC5/1)).

Comment: Thanks, that's almost good, it does the trick but I have errors when the phrase contains brackets. for example, if the string to match is: `Incompatible device (connection error) (x3)` then the number is not captured as a group (cause I don't have any ';' character after it).
Any ideas of how to address this issue?

Comment: @AndroidNewbie Add a reluctant qualifier after `[^;]+`, i.e. make it `[^;]+?`.